# First step in a reaction between an acyl chloride and sodium acetate in acetic acid

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism

> What would the first step be in a reaction between acyl chloride and sodium acetate in the presence of acetic acid?

I'm a bit confused because I'm not quite sure which step would occur first. I was thinking that perhaps the sodium acetate will first attack the carbonyl carbon, but I'm also wondering if it would be possible that sodium acetate would first react with acetic acid, turning the latter into an anion that could react with the acid chloride forming an anhydride.

Comment: If the sodium acetate reacts with the acetic acid then the result is sodium acetate and acetic acid. You have only exchanged sodium ion between acetic acid molecules.

Comment: @Waylander I guess the OP means by "acid chloride"  an acyl chloride, particularly acetyl chloride and the reaction $$\ce{CH3COCl + CH3COONa ->[CH3COOH] (CH3CO)2O + NaCl}$$.

Comment: Hi! Thank you so much for answering
Yes @Poutnik, that's the reaction I'm referring to, thank you for this!

Comment: My other question though is, what is the carboxylic acid used for? Will it be fine to just use any other group with an alcohol group like, say, butanol?

Comment: Acetic acid serves as a solvent. Butanol would IMHO react $\ce{CH3COCl + BuOH -> CH3COOBu + HCl}$